# Error-Required type mismatch: Thread Found:Unit of measurement

Tags: multithreading, kotlin

Why does the error - Type mismatch Required:Thread Found:Unit appear when creating a thread in the class ?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var thread: Thread? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        thread = Thread {
            try {
                println("Hello")
            } catch (ex: IOException) {
                ex.printStackTrace()
            }
        }.start()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split your declaration and your start. Here, you are assigning the value of `.start()` to your `thread` value. That value is `Unit` since `.start()` has a void return.

You can do:

```
thread = Thread {
    try {
        println("Hello")
    } catch (ex: IOException) {
        ex.printStackTrace()
    }
}

thread.start()
```